# MailItem.Delete refusing to delete item in Deleted Items folder

Tags: vb.net, mailitem

Not sure why the following code is not permanently deleting the `MailItem` from the `Deleted Items` folder.

The `MailItem` certainly ends up in the `Deleted Items` folder, but the `Delete` seems to do nothing. Placing a second `Delete` causes an exception as you would expect because it's not there.

I can manually delete the `MailItem` permanently via Outlook.

Code:

```
Dim oOLapp as Outlook.Application
Dim oMapi as Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oFolder as Outlook.Folder
Dim oMailItem as Outlook.MailItem

oOLapp = GetObject([Class]:="Outlook.Application")
oMapi = oOLapp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
oFolder = oMapi.oFolders(oMapi.DefaultStore.Displayname).Folders("Deleted Items")

oMailItem = oOLapp.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\sometestmail.msg")
oMailItem = oMailItem.Move(oFolder) ' Now in Deleted items Folder. Verified
' Do other stuff with email
' .
' .
' .
oMailItem.Delete()
oMailItem = nothing
```

Comment: Probably because that's what delete DOES... Move it to the deleted folder. If your outlook is  set to delete on close.. they should disappear when you close it. Otherwise, they will stay there.

Comment: BUt you may want to check this link http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?327965-RESOLVED-Permanently-Delete-Outlook-Items

Comment: Or this https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27503590/VBA-to-permanently-delete-emails-instead-of-moving-them-to-the-deleted-folder.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To permanently delete a `MailItem` you have to loop through the `Items` within the `Deleted` folder.

To do this have a look at the following code:

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application

Dim oMapi As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders = oMapi.Folders
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oFolders(oMapi.DefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Deleted Items")

Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\sometestmail.msg"), Outlook.MailItem)
oMailItem.UserProperties.Add("DeleteMe", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText)
oMailItem.Move(oFolder)
oMailItem = Nothing

For Each item As Outlook.MailItem In oFolder.Items
    Dim oProperty As Outlook.UserProperty = item.UserProperties.Find("DeleteMe")

    If oProperty IsNot Nothing Then
        item.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

My code will differ to yours as I have turned **Option Strict On**. I suggest you do the same. This will help in the long run.

Note that I am setting a `UserProperty` to the `MailItem` before moving it to the `Deleted` folder. This will help identify that single `MailItem` that you want to permanently delete. *If* you want to permanently delete all `MailItems` in the `Deleted` folder then this is the code you would need:

```
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application

Dim oMapi As Outlook.NameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim oFolders As Outlook.Folders = oMapi.Folders
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = oFolders(oMapi.DefaultStore.DisplayName).Folders("Deleted Items")

Dim oMailItem As Outlook.MailItem = CType(oApp.Session.OpenSharedItem("C:\sometestmail.msg"), Outlook.MailItem)
oMailItem.Move(oFolder)
oMailItem = Nothing

For i = oFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1
    CType(oFolder.Items(i), Outlook.MailItem).Delete()
Next
```

In order for this to work you need to loop through the `Deleted` folder *backwards*. Looking at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343.aspx) documentation it states:

> The Delete method deletes a single item in a collection. To delete all items in the Items collection of a folder, you must delete each item starting with the last item in the folder. For example, in the items collection of a folder, AllItems, if there are n number of items in the folder, start deleting the item at AllItems.Item(n), decrementing the index each time until you delete AllItems.Item(1).